# Combinar dos números binarios

Tags: java

Buenas tengo una duda de java y es que me pide calcular el binario de dosnumeros y luego mezclar los dos numeros binarios.
No se como mezclar los numeros bnarios me podrian ayudar

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Si compartes lo que tienes hecho hasta el momento te podremos ayudar mejor :)

Comment: Define "mezclar" en términos que podamos entender. En términos de programación.